# HOW TO INSTALL A NODE V>14 IN WINDOWS 8?? Please someone help me

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, windows-8, create-react-app

Right now I use node version **13.14.0** but to use the new version of create-react-app **v5.0.0**, I need to use node version **14 or later** , which is not supported in windows 8. Does anyone have a solution for this?

[error in creating a react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc8XU.png)

Comment: New version 14.0.0 says: (node --version) this program can be run only on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Windows 8 not supporting version 14.

You can download whichever version of version 14 you want here:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/

You can also download the LTS version from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: It is saying, "This application is only supported on windows 8.1, windows server 2012 R2 or higher." and I'm on windows 8 not 8.1